# How to send Request and parse json plus save

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

As If I am new to iOS i need to know how to make request.

I am trying to make request like :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",dk.baseURL,@"daantest"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
NSString *sendString = @"abc";
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sendString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[sendString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:pd];
    [urlConnection start];
```

please guide me .

Comment: may you please specify your problem a little clear? what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create your request like :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) {
    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];


}];
```

so you can get your data here .